# Sorting associative array with variable keys in PHP

Tags: php, sorting, associative-array

i have the following associative array

word => count

where word is an english word ('more', 'creme', 'car' and so on), while count is the number of times that word appeared in a given string.

I want to sort by count.

Thx.

Ps.
I tried usort but didn't work

Comment: Whos throwing close requests? Whos downvoting? All that without explanation. Its like when someone doesn't understand a question, he throws a -1 or close.

Comment: SO shouldn't allow questions that contain all variations of "didn't work"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$fruits = array("d" => 4, "a" => 3, "b" => 2, "c" => 1);
asort($fruits, SORT_NUMERIC);
foreach ($fruits as $key => $val) {
    echo "$key = $val\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: +1 for a really nice and concise answer!